# one-many-many assoc find conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include

I've got the following models:

**project.rb**

```
has_many :tasks
```

**task.rb**

```
belongs_to :project
has_many :assignments
has_many :users, :through => :assignments
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :assignments
has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments
```

**assignment.rb**

```
belongs_to :task
belongs_to :user
```

**So for example:**
Project.first.title #=> "Manhattan"
Project.first.tasks.map(&:name) # => ['Find Scientists', 'Find Money', 'Find Location']
Project.first.tasks.first.users.map(&:full_name) #=> ['James Maxwell', 'Evariste Galois', 'Jules Verne']

**My first question is:**
How can I find all the persons' names possibly with symbol to proc in one shot, I tried:

`Project.first.tasks.users.full_name #=> AND FAILED`
`Project.first.tasks.map(&:users).full_name #=> AND FAILED`
`Project.first.tasks.map(&:users).map(&:full_name) #=> AND FAILED`

Any ideas?

And I think this following question might be in the same ball park:

How can I do a find of Project with conditions that search the 'full_name' attribute of the users its tasks?

**Example**

`Project.all(:include => {:tasks => :users}, :conditions => ['tasks.users.full_name LIKE ?', query]) #this failed`

I think the problem is at the 'tasks.users'.

Thanks everyone, have a happy thanksgiving!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one you'll want to do something like this:

```
Project.first.tasks.map { |t| t.users.map(&:full_name) }.flatten
```

The reason for this is that you want to iterate through all the tasks, then all the users in each task. Without the flatten this would give you a 2-dimensional array.

And for the second one your find should be:

```
Project.all(:include => {:tasks => :users}, :conditions => ['users.full_name LIKE ?', query])
```

Writing `users.full_name` implies to the SQL engine that you're looking for the `full_name` field on the `users` table.

Comment: Oh I see, so I actually didn't have to do
:conditions => ['tasks.users.full_name Like ?', query] because the users inclusion allows 1) users to be used sort-of "stand-alone" and 2) properly scoped to tasks when queried.

The search for all full names of users of a project's tasks works! -- Is there a computer-science/mathematical preference as to why we can chain the many-to-many associations to yield some 'grand-total' attributes? Like 
Project.first.tasks.users.map(&:full_name)

I can imagine scenarios where people need this
Thanks Radar. Plz consider case closed. Happy Holidays!